# Add custom text to jqGrid navigator buttons in Struts2-jQuery-Grid

Tags: jsp, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am using struts2 jqGrid. I have enabled `navigatorSearch="true"`. So It shows the search button. I want to add a text to the button saying `Search` I read it [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Anavigator) that I need to add the `searchtext` attribute to add custom text. But I dont know where to add this attribute. I tried adding it in `navigatorSearchOptions` but it failed. This is my (partial)grid code :

```
<sjg:grid      
   ..
    navigator="true"
    navigatorView="false"
    navigatorDelete="false" 
    navigatorAdd="false"
    navigatorEdit="false"
    navigatorSearch="true"
    navigatorSearchOptions="{sopt:['eq' ,'cn']}"
    >
```

How do I add text to search & reload buttons??
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you want to add text that appears when the mouse hovers over the search button, or add text to the button itself? In lieu of the default icon for search, or with said icon?

Comment: @RicardoPerezHernando I have to add the text on the search button itself. Means Next to the icon